# Motion terminates after about 1 minute

Tags: motion

Running Motion 4.2.2 on a Pi 3 B+. Everything seems to work. I have the video stream in the browser on :8080. It detect motions, records and store an avi file in /home/pi/logs/motion/. After aboute 1 minute, the image suddenly freezes in the browser. The program has terminated.

I installed the latest version the following way.

```
wget https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion/releases/download/release-4.2.2/pi_stretch_motion_4.2.2-1_armhf.deb

sudo apt-get install gdebi-core

sudo gdebi pi_stretch_motion_4.2.2-1_armhf.deb
```

And a link to motion.conf

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmv8o97tpkzv41m/motion.conf?dl=0
```

To verify that Motion is functioning propperly I run Motion in terminal mode with the following command, with and without sudo.

```
motion -d 9 -k 9 -l /etc/mo/logg
```

And here is the logg that I get.

```
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_startup: Motion 4.2.2 Started
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_startup: Using default log type (ALL)
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_startup: Using log type (ALL) log level (ALL)
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] conf_output_parms: Writing configuration parameters from all files (1):
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] Thread 0 - Config file: /home/pi/motion.conf
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] daemon                    off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] setup_mode                off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] pid_file                  
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] log_file                  /etc/mo/logg
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] log_level                 9
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] log_type                  ALL
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] quiet                     on
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] native_language           on
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] camera_name               
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] camera_id                 0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] target_dir                /home/pi/logs/motion
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] videodevice               /dev/video0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] vid_control_params        
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_palette              17
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] input                     -1
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] norm                      0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] frequency                 0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] auto_brightness           0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] tunerdevice               
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] roundrobin_frames         1
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] roundrobin_skip           1
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] roundrobin_switchfilter   off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] netcam_url                
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] netcam_highres            
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] netcam_userpass           
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] netcam_keepalive          off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] netcam_proxy              
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] netcam_tolerant_check     off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] netcam_use_tcp            on
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] mmalcam_name              
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] mmalcam_control_params    
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] width                     960
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] height                    720
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] framerate                 2
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] minimum_frame_time        0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] rotate                    0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] flip_axis                 none
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] locate_motion_mode        off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] locate_motion_style       box
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] text_left                 PUNKT MOTION
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] text_right                %Y-%m-%d\n%T-%q
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] text_changes              off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] text_scale                1
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] text_event                %Y%m%d%H%M%S
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] emulate_motion            off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] threshold                 200
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] threshold_maximum         0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] threshold_tune            off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] noise_level               32
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] noise_tune                on
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] despeckle_filter          EedDl
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] area_detect               
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] mask_file                 
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] mask_privacy              
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] smart_mask_speed          0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] lightswitch_percent       0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] lightswitch_frames        5
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] minimum_motion_frames     1
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] event_gap                 60
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] pre_capture               0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] post_capture              100
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] on_event_start            
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] on_event_end              
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] on_picture_save           
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] on_area_detected          
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] on_motion_detected        
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] on_movie_start            
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] on_movie_end              
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] on_camera_lost            
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] on_camera_found           
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] picture_output            off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] picture_output_motion     off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] picture_type              jpeg
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] picture_quality           75
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] picture_exif              
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] picture_filename          %Y%m%d%H%M%S-%q
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] snapshot_interval         0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] snapshot_filename         %v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S-snapshot
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_output              on
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_output_motion       off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_max_time            0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_bps                 400000
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_quality             45
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_codec               mpeg4
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_duplicate_frames    off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_passthrough         off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_filename            %t-%v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_extpipe_use         off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] movie_extpipe             
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] timelapse_interval        0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] timelapse_mode            daily
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] timelapse_fps             30
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] timelapse_codec           mpg
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] timelapse_filename        %Y%m%d-timelapse
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] video_pipe                
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] video_pipe_motion         
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_port           8080
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_ipv6           off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_localhost      off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_parms          0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_interface      0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_auth_method    0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_authentication 
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_tls            off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_cert           
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_key            
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webcontrol_cors_header    
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_port               8081
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_localhost          off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_auth_method        0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_authentication     
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_tls                off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_cors_header        
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_preview_scale      25
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_preview_newline    off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_preview_method     0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_quality            50
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_grey               off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_motion             off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_maxrate            1
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] stream_limit              0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] database_type             
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] database_dbname           
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] database_host             localhost
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] database_port             0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] database_user             
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] database_password         
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] database_busy_timeout     0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] sql_log_picture           off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] sql_log_snapshot          off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] sql_log_movie             off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] sql_log_timelapse         off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] sql_query_start           
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] sql_query_stop            
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] sql_query                 
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_type                0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_auto                off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_port                
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_motorx              0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_motorx_reverse      off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_motory              0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_motory_reverse      off
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_maxx                0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_minx                0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_maxy                0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_miny                0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_homex               128
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_homey               128
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_iomojo_id           0
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_step_angle_x        10
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_step_angle_y        10
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_move_wait           10
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_speed               255
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_stepsize            40
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] track_generic_move        
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] camera                    
[0:motion] [INF] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] camera_dir                
[0:motion] [DBG] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_ntc: v4l2   : available
[0:motion] [DBG] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_ntc: bktr   : not available
[0:motion] [DBG] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_ntc: webp   : available
[0:motion] [DBG] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_ntc: mmal   : available
[0:motion] [DBG] [ALL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_ntc: ffmpeg : available
[0:motion] [DBG] [DBL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_ntc: mysql  : available
[0:motion] [DBG] [DBL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_ntc: sqlite3: available
[0:motion] [DBG] [DBL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_ntc: pgsql  : available
[0:motion] [DBG] [DBL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] motion_ntc: nls    : available
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_start_strm: Starting all camera streams on port 8081
[0:motion] [DBG] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_mhd_features_basic: Basic authentication: available
[0:motion] [DBG] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_mhd_features_digest: Digest authentication: available
[0:motion] [DBG] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_mhd_features_ipv6: IPV6: available
[0:motion] [DBG] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_mhd_features_tls: SSL/TLS: available
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_strm_ntc: Started camera 0 stream on port 8081
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_start_ctrl: Starting webcontrol on port 8080
[0:motion] [DBG] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_mhd_features_basic: Basic authentication: available
[0:motion] [DBG] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_mhd_features_digest: Digest authentication: available
[0:motion] [DBG] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_mhd_features_ipv6: IPV6: available
[0:motion] [DBG] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_mhd_features_tls: SSL/TLS: available
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Jul 25 07:40:38] webu_start_ctrl: Started webcontrol on port 8080
[0:motion] [DBG] [VID] [Jul 25 07:40:38] bktr_mutex_init: BKTR is not enabled.
[0:motion] [NTC] [ENC] [Jul 25 07:40:38] ffmpeg_global_init: ffmpeg libavcodec version 57.64.101 libavformat version 57.56.101
[0:motion] [DBG] [DBL] [Jul 25 07:40:38] dbse_global_init: Initializing database
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:40:38] translate_init: SprÃ¥k: Svenska
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:40:38] motion_start_thread: Camera ID: 0 is from /home/pi/motion.conf
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:40:38] motion_start_thread: Camera ID: 0 Camera Name: (null) Device: /dev/video0
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:40:38] main: Waiting for threads to finish, pid: 2519
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:40:38] motion_init: Camera 0 started: motion detection Enabled
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] vid_start: Opening V4L2 device
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_open: Using videodevice /dev/video0 and input -1
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_capability: ------------------------
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_capability: cap.driver: "bm2835 mmal"
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_capability: cap.card: "mmal service 16.1"
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_capability: cap.bus_info: "platform:bcm2835-v4l2"
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_capability: cap.capabilities=0x85200005
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_capability: ------------------------
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_capability: - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_capability: - VIDEO_OVERLAY
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_capability: - READWRITE
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_device_capability: - STREAMING
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_input_select: Name = "Camera 0", type 0x00000002, status 00000000
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_input_select: Name = "Camera 0"- CAMERA
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_norm_select: Device does not support specifying PAL/NTSC norm
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_pixfmt_set: Testing palette YU12 (960x720)
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_pixfmt_set: Using palette YU12 (960x720)
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_pixfmt_set: Bytesperlines 960 sizeimage 1036800 colorspace 00000001
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ---------Controls---------
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   V4L2 ID   Name and Range
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963776 Brightness, 0 to 100
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963777 Contrast, -100 to 100
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963778 Saturation, -100 to 100
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963790 Red Balance, 1 to 7999
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963791 Blue Balance, 1 to 7999
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963796 Horizontal Flip, 0 to 1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963797 Vertical Flip, 0 to 1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963800 Power Line Frequency, 0 to 3
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 0 Disabled
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 1 50 Hz
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 2 60 Hz
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 3 Auto
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963803 Sharpness, -100 to 100
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963807 Color Effects, 0 to 15
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 0 None
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 1 Black & White
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 2 Sepia
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 3 Negative
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 4 Emboss
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 5 Sketch
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 6 Sky Blue
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 7 Grass Green
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 8 Skin Whiten
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 9 Vivid
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 10 Aqua
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 11 Art Freeze
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 12 Silhouette
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 13 Solarization
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 14 Antique
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 15 Set Cb/Cr
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963810 Rotate, 0 to 360
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID09963818 Color Effects, CbCr, 0 to 65535
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10029518 Video Bitrate Mode, 0 to 1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 0 Variable Bitrate
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 1 Constant Bitrate
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10029519 Video Bitrate, 25000 to 25000000
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10029538 Repeat Sequence Header, 0 to 1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10029670 H264 I-Frame Period, 0 to 2147483647
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10029671 H264 Level, 0 to 11
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 0 1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 1 1b
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 2 1.1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 3 1.2
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 4 1.3
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 5 2
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 6 2.1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 7 2.2
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 8 3
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 9 3.1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 10 3.2
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 11 4
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10029675 H264 Profile, 0 to 4
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 0 Baseline
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 1 Constrained Baseline
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 2 Main
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 4 High
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10094849 Auto Exposure, 0 to 3
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 0 Auto Mode
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 1 Manual Mode
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10094850 Exposure Time, Absolute, 1 to 10000
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10094851 Exposure, Dynamic Framerate, 0 to 1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10094867 Auto Exposure, Bias, 0 to 24
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10094868 White Balance, Auto & Preset, 0 to 9
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 0 Manual
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 1 Auto
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 2 Incandescent
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 3 Fluorescent
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 4 Fluorescent H
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 5 Horizon
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 6 Daylight
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 7 Flash
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 8 Cloudy
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 9 Shade
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10094870 Image Stabilization, 0 to 1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10094871 ISO Sensitivity, 0 to 4
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10094872 ISO Sensitivity, Auto, 0 to 1
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 0 Manual
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 1 Auto
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10094873 Exposure, Metering Mode, 0 to 2
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 0 Average
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 1 Center Weighted
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 2 Spot
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10094874 Scene Mode, 0 to 13
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 0 None
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 8 Night
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list:   menu item: Value 11 Sports
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: ID10291459 Compression Quality, 1 to 100
[1:ml1] [INF] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_ctrls_list: --------------------------
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_mmap_set: mmap information: frames=4
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_mmap_set: 0 length=1036800 Address (6d002000)
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_mmap_set: 1 length=1036800 Address (6cf04000)
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_mmap_set: 2 length=1036800 Address (6ce06000)
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:38] v4l2_mmap_set: 3 length=1036800 Address (6cd08000)
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:40:39] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:39] v4l2_capture: 1) vid_source->pframe -1
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:39] v4l2_capture: 2) vid_source->pframe -1
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:39] v4l2_capture: 3) vid_source->pframe 0 vid_source->buf.index 0
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:39] v4l2_capture: the_buffer index 0 Address (6d002000)
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:39] v4l2_capture: 1) vid_source->pframe 0
and more of the same ....
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:47] v4l2_capture: 3) vid_source->pframe 1 vid_source->buf.index 1
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:47] v4l2_capture: the_buffer index 1 Address (6cf04000)
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:47] v4l2_capture: 1) vid_source->pframe 1
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:47] v4l2_capture: 2) vid_source->pframe 1
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:47] v4l2_capture: 3) vid_source->pframe 2 vid_source->buf.index 2
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:47] v4l2_capture: the_buffer index 2 Address (6ce06000)
[1:ml1] [INF] [EVT] [jul 25 07:40:47] event_new_video: Source FPS 2
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ENC] [jul 25 07:40:47] ffmpeg_set_codec: Low fps. Encoding 2 frames into a 10 frames container.
[1:ml1] [INF] [ENC] [jul 25 07:40:47] ffmpeg_set_quality: mpeg4 codec vbr/crf/bit_rate: 1332
[1:ml1] [NTC] [EVT] [jul 25 07:40:47] event_newfile: File of type 8 saved to: /home/pi/logs/motion/0-01-20200725074047.avi
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:40:47] motion_detected: Motion detected - starting event 1
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:48] v4l2_capture: 1) vid_source->pframe 2
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:48] v4l2_capture: 2) vid_source->pframe 2
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:48] v4l2_capture: 3) vid_source->pframe 3 vid_source->buf.index 3
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:40:48] v4l2_capture: the_buffer index 3 Address (6cd08000)
and more of the same.......
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:41:01] v4l2_capture: 3) vid_source->pframe 2 vid_source->buf.index 2
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:41:01] v4l2_capture: the_buffer index 2 Address (6ce06000)
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:41:02] v4l2_capture: 1) vid_source->pframe 2
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:41:02] v4l2_capture: 2) vid_source->pframe 2
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:41:02] v4l2_capture: 3) vid_source->pframe 3 vid_source->buf.index 3
[1:ml1] [DBG] [VID] [jul 25 07:41:02] v4l2_capture: the_buffer index 3 Address (6cd08000)
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:41:02] mlp_actions: End of event 1
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:41:02] motion_loop: Thread exiting
[1:ml1] [INF] [ALL] [jul 25 07:41:02] motion_cleanup: Calling vid_close() from motion_cleanup
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:41:02] vid_close: Cleaning up V4L2 device
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [jul 25 07:41:02] v4l2_cleanup: Closing video device /dev/video0
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:41:03] main: Threads finished
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:41:03] main: Motion terminating
[0:motion] [DBG] [ALL] [jul 25 07:41:03] dbse_global_deinit: Closing MYSQL
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [jul 25 07:41:03] motion_remove_pid: Closing logfile (/etc/mo/logg).
```

Comment: You should post `motions.conf`.

Comment: ...and any other related config files.